# Python dde module install

Tags: python, dde

How can I import dde in python 2.7?
I took over a job about measurement automation using python. However, the author of the code import a module "dde". My pycharm reminds me that "no module named dde".

Maybe I need to install dde module? But I cannot find dde module installation.

I have already installed pywin32(214version).

new to this, hope an answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try import package name as in this case is import dde or from dde import *

Comment: From your command line run `pip install PyZDDE`

Comment: sorry, but pyzdde seems not what I need

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I find a file "dde.pyd" in "Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin".
Now the error is :

import dde

ImportError: DLL load failed:

Answer (score 0):

In my script I use:

```
import ddeclient.dde_client as ddec
```

The DDE client is available at:
[DDE Client (Python recipe)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577654/)

I've downloaded this client and saved it to a folder named "ddeclient" in the same folder level where my script is located. 
It works for me. Hope that helps you!